# readyState always 1 and status is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, readystate

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting readyState as 1 and status as undefined for the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delsub').on('submit', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'delRept.php',
            type: 'POST',            
            data: "&delsub=delsub",
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);
            }
         });
         console.log(xhr.readyState);
         console.log(xhr.status);
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: because where you are logging in console, ajax is not finished.

Comment: As the request is async, you're logging `readyState` before the request completes, hence it's always `1`. Where are you seeing `status` as `undefined`, I can't see it anywhere in your code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry. If I give console.log(xhr.status) it shows undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ajax is asynchronous call, it doesn't wait for the result instead it jumps to next line whatever is written there. So in your case when you call your ajax on `submit` method:

```
 var xhr = $.ajax({}); // here you assign the ajax to a var xhr
```

and right after that call you have used to output the state to the console with:

```
console.log(xhr.readyState); // logs the state of the ajax
```

---

So in your case issue is ajax is async call so whenever ajax code is assigned to `xhr` right after that you are logging the state. so everytime it will log `1`.

---

If you go through the documentation you can see that there is a `complete:fn` callback, you can use it:

```
$('.delsub').on('submit', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'delRept.php',
        type: 'POST',            
        data: "&delsub=delsub",
        success: function(d){
            console.log(d);
        },
        complete:function(xhr){
            console.log(xhr.readyState);
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
     });
});
```

or if you want to do some operations on different statuses then you can use `statusCode:{}`:

```
$('.delsub').on('submit', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'delRept.php',
        type: 'POST',            
        data: "&delsub=delsub",
        statusCode:{
            200:function(){
               console.log(xhr.readyState);
               console.log(xhr.status);
               alert('200');
            }, 
            304:function(){
               console.log(xhr.readyState);
               console.log(xhr.status);
               alert('304');
            }
        },
        success: function(d){
            console.log(d);
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the request is asynchronous, and you're logging readyState before the request completes, hence it's always `1`. If you need to check those values you need to put them in the `success` callback so that they execute after the request has completed:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: 'delRept.php',
    type: 'POST',            
    data: "&delsub=delsub",
    success: function(d){
        console.log(d);
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});
```